# Python post to ms teams

Tags: python, python-requests, webhooks, microsoft-teams, urllib3

Trying to post a message to MS Teams webhook from Python below:

```
pmr = urllib3.PoolManager()
text='hello world'
message = {"Test":text}
enco_message = json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')
r=pmr.request('POST',url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body=enco_message)
print(r.status)
```

But this does not send any message to teams and returns response status `400`. Not sure what is to be changed in the code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: [pyteams](https://pypi.org/project/pymsteams/) is a nice library to check

Comment: Any clue why the above code does not work @octopus, thanks.

Comment: Try setting `Content-Length` https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/microsoft-teams-webhooks-error/m-p/152055/highlight/true#M11047

Comment: @omdurg : Try setting content-length and let us know if still  doesn't resolve this.

Comment: Added `Content-Length` in header, but does not post the message, status returned is `400`, thanks@fdermishin

Comment: Added `Content-Length` in header, but does not post the message, status returned is `400`, thanks @Manish-MSFT

Comment: Can you have same implementation with Pyteams library? For more info [here](https://pypi.org/project/pymsteams/)

Comment: Tried with `text` payload and it works @ Manish-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked by explicitly specifying `text` keyword in the `json`, like below:

```
pmr = urllib3.PoolManager()
msg='hello world'
message = {"text":msg}
enco_message = json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')
r=pmr.request('POST',url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
body=enco_message)
```

The payload only works with the keyword `text`.